# Asp.net - Update related data - Get null when submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I got stuck on a problem with returning from view to controller with related data, every time I submit my form with related data, the related data becomes null. (OrderRows)

I check the Chorme develop tool and saw that I do post the OrderRows as row.Id but can see them in Visual Studio as an variable

Classes

```
public class OrderModel
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int OrderID { get; set; }
   public List<OrderRow> OrderRows { get; set; }
}

public class OrderRow
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int OrderRowID { get; set; }
    public OrderModel OrderModel { get; set; }

}
```

Edit Controller (GET)

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    OrderModel orderModel = db.OrderModel.Where(b => b.Id == id).Include(b => b.OrderRows).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(orderModel);
}
```

Delivered controler (Post, is activated when submitting the form)

```
public ActionResult Delivered(OrderModel orderModel, FormCollection formCollection)
{
        //db.Entry(orderModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //Set state to Delivered
        //db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");   
}
```

Editview

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID): @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderRows)




<div class="row">
    @Html.Label("Delivery information")
    <br />
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <br />

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <br />      
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    @foreach (var row in Model.OrderRows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="@row.OrderRowID">
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => row.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => row.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => row.OrderID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => row.OrderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => row.OrderRowID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => row.OrderRowID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => row.OrderModel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => row.OrderModel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>           
        </tr>

    }
    </table>
        <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Mark as Delivered" formaction="/OrderModels/Delivered" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You are posting to the controller action from view? Which action is the one supposed to get data?

Comment: Excuse me, happened to take with Get controller, when it was post controls that would be in the post. Both are in the post now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to use `OrderRow` instead of `OrderModel`. If I understand what you need, you want to get (one) `OrderModel` and include (many) `OrderRows`. If that's what you want you should use `OrderRow` as your model in your view:

```
OrderRow orderRows = db.OrderRow.Where(b => b.OrderModel.Id == id).ToList();

return View(orderRows);
```

Then you want to change the model in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<OrderRow>
```

This way, you can have all the `OrderRows` including its `OrderModel`.

Comment: Hello, 

I had that solution in mind. But curious if it can be solved so that I'm trying at the moment

This is how it looks in the local watch panel, no clue if it helps. http://i.imgur.com/YwaDiXP.png

Comment: In what I am seeing in your current set up, you can't really get OrderModel.OrderRows when you postback from EditView. You may want to refactor your models, or you can give a try on my suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is defined as `public ActionResult Edit(int? id)`, meaning it expects a value of `id`, of type int.

You won't get any other data through it, if you want the value from `OrderRows` you need to either change your form to submit it as `id`, or update your controller to accept a `public ActionResult Edit(int OrderRows)`.

Either way, you are still also submitting a lot of junk that isn't being picked up by the controller, you need to only submit the values the controller is defined to accept (as above). What you really want to be doing is `@html.BeginFrom(viewModelClass)`'ing a viewmodel and submitting that to your controller with all the values.

Eg:

```
Public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model)
{
   var value = model.OrderRows
}
```